# Is it possible to undeploy a Google Cloud AutoML Vision Image Classification model when it's not being used?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl

I know how to undeploy/redeploy an Object Detection model - but my overall project uses both Object Detection and Image Classification. What's the best way to save money when we're not using both?

It's easy to remove the deployment of the Object Detection model, and then re-deploy it when we have data to process. Can the same be done for the Image Classification models?

Answer (score 0):

In both Object Detection and Image Classification you pay based on resource usage.

Regarding your question, it’s important to take into account that you pay per [node deployed](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/pricing) as the model’s associated resources remain allocated in order to prevent delays in your predictions. That’s why in order to not incur charges when you are not using the service you should [undeploy](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/undeploy#automl_undeploy_model-web-integrated) the models. You can do this in both Object Detection and Image Classification.

---